# NumberFormatException for Valid String

Tags: java, numberformatexception

This is my below code which converts string to long datatype.

```
/**
     * Parses a String into primitive long
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
public static long parseLong(String str){
        try {
            long result = Long.parseLong(str);
            return result;
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            //do nothing or log it
            return 0L;
    }
}
```

But for this String `2006-09-11 22:01:13` whenever it is passed to the above `parseLong` method, I always get this exception-

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2006-09-11 22:01:13"
```

I need to convert `String to Long`. And in this method any type of String can be passed. So while I was debugging the code, I found out that it is throwing exception for this string- `"2006-09-11 22:01:13"`. As far as my understanding goes, it shouldn't be throwing exception right? as we can convert any string to long by using `Long.parseLong` method right?

Can anyone explain why I am getting this exception? As I am confuse now.. :-/

Comment: What do you expect as a result from this method call?

Comment: I think the question is: what's java equivalent of php's strtotime.

Comment: I am trying to convert String to Long. And I can pass any String into that method, So when I was debugging the code I found out that this `2006-09-11 22:01:13` got passed as a string to that method. And as per my understanding goes any String should get converted to Long by `Long.parseLong` Am I right? If Yes, then why this exception is getting thrown?

Comment: No, not *any* `String`.  Bear in mind, even that has to be converted to a `Long` through a `Date` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings with special characters can not directly parsed to long or `int`. If you want to parse it to long or any type replace the special character first with ("").

or otherwise if you want to parse the above string as date then use simpleDate format as like this

```
SimpleDateFormat parser= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date d = null;

try {
    d = parser.parse(str);
            System.out.println("Parsed date is "+d);
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then the output will be
`Parsed date is Mon Sep 11 22:01:13 IST 2006`

Comment: Thanks Ram. So you are saying, any string with special characters (like what?) cannot be parsed to long or int? If yes, how can I make the above method more generic to handle all the scenarios that I posted in the question to convert it to Long from String data type?

Comment: you want the string to be converted as `20060911220113`?

Comment: I think, I got your point. So basically I cannot represent this string `2006-09-11 22:01:13` to long data type as it is? I need to remove the special characters to make it proper long? I was thinking that I can represent the same string `2006-09-11 22:01:13` as the Long as well.

Comment: if you want so, then do as like this str= str.replace("-", "").replace(" ","").replace(":", "");  System.out.println(parseLong(str));

Answer (score 1):

Because your  date `String` isn't a `Long` or a number to begin with. You want to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your date string to a valid Date object.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be an exact integral number held in a string. e.g. "12345676" nothing else than a digit. "2006-09-11 22:01:13" contains whole lot of stuffs than a digit like "-" (hyphen), ":" (colon), " " (space), which are not digits.

Comment: Is there any restriction on that as well? Like we cannot convert String to Long if it has anything like that you mentioned above? As far as my understanding goes, I thought we can convert any string to long by using `Long.parseLong` method. Am I right?

Comment: @TechGeeky No, `Long.parseLong` only parses strings that represent a valid `long` value and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, so how can I make the above method more generic to handle all the scenarios that I posted in the question to convert it to Long from String data type?